# HTACCESS 404 redirection different for different folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using htaccess file for handling and forwarding in case of 404 Error. Now I have to redirect files of a particular folder to another page(which is not defined in htaccess). I create a separate .htaccess file for that folder. But it doesn't work.

Please suggest me, what is the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Specify _"it doesn't work"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Now I have to redirect files of a particular folder to another
>   page(which is not defined in htaccess).`

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^somefolder /another-page [L,NC]
```